# Generate the full polynomial regression formula, not just coefficients using sklearn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics, scikit-learn, polynomial-math

Background: I'm doing polynomial regression modeling using scikit-learn. With the regression model generated, you can get a list of coefficients.

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(X_, Y_)
print model.coef_
```

Results:

> [  0.00000000e+00   -3.69049908e+00   9.45845788e-03   4.79401992e+01
>      1.13710193e+01    2.55613693e+01]

It means Y = 0 + -3.69 X1 + 0.00945 X2 + 47.9 X1^2 + 11.3 X1X2 + 25.5 X2^2

But you don't know which terms they are representing with first glimpse. You'll have to check with the list to find out which is which. I hope to make the computer print the whole formula, not just the coefficients.

Is there a way to do this? I don't see any function in sklearn that can do this. So I'm thinking about writing a function to generate the ordered list for polynomial terms

So if I input 1, there's only 1 decision variable, the polynomial terms are like [1, X1]

For input 2, it's [1, X1, X2, X1^2, X1X2, X2^2].

For input 3, it's [1, X1, X2, X1^2, X1X2, X2^2, X1X3, X2X3, X3^2, X1^3, X1^2 * X2, X1 * X2^2, .........X3^3]

So I hope to write this function. But I'm having a hard time figuring out the ranking algorithm. Can anyone give me a hint on this? Is there a pattern I can follow when generating the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out myself.

```
print poly.powers_
```

use this code, and for n variables, it looks like

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [2 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 2 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 2]
 [3 0 0 0]
 [2 1 0 0]
 [2 0 1 0]
 [2 0 0 1]
 [1 2 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 2 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 2]
 [0 3 0 0]
 [0 2 1 0]
 [0 2 0 1]
 [0 1 2 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 2]
 [0 0 3 0]
 [0 0 2 1]
 [0 0 1 2]
 [0 0 0 3]
 [4 0 0 0]
 [3 1 0 0]
 [3 0 1 0]
 [3 0 0 1]
 [2 2 0 0]
 [2 1 1 0]
 [2 1 0 1]
 [2 0 2 0]
 [2 0 1 1]
 [2 0 0 2]
 [1 3 0 0]
 [1 2 1 0]
 [1 2 0 1]
 [1 1 2 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 2]
 [1 0 3 0]
 [1 0 2 1]
 [1 0 1 2]
 [1 0 0 3]
 [0 4 0 0]
 [0 3 1 0]
 [0 3 0 1]
 [0 2 2 0]
 [0 2 1 1]
 [0 2 0 2]
 [0 1 3 0]
 [0 1 2 1]
 [0 1 1 2]
 [0 1 0 3]
 [0 0 4 0]
 [0 0 3 1]
 [0 0 2 2]
 [0 0 1 3]
 [0 0 0 4]]
```

And the formula can build on this sheet.

I'm not sure it I made it clear, so if anyone sees this thread and has similar problems, just leave a message and I can further explain.

See this page: [sklearn: how to get coefficients of polynomial features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290976/sklearn-how-to-get-coefficients-of-polynomial-features?rq=1)

Comment: Can you explain more on how to turn that sheet into a formula?