# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'powers_'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Here is my program using sklearn.

```
 X = np.array([[1, 2, 4],[2, 3, 9]]).T    
 print(X)
 y = np.array([1, 4, 16])
 X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(X)
 print(X_poly)
 model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)
 model.fit(X_poly,y)
 print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
 print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)
 print(X_poly.powers_)
 X_predict = np.array([[3,3]])
 print(model.predict(feats.transform(X_predict)))
```

I have these errors:

```
 ---> 17 print(X_poly.powers_)
 18 
 19 X_predict = np.array([[3,3]])

 AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'powers_'
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting `X_poly` into two lines should do the trick here:

```
X_poly_temp = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly = X_poly_temp.fit_transform(X)
print(X_poly_temp.powers_)
```

Comment: can you explain me this please powers : 

[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [2 0]
 [1 1]
 [0 2]]

Comment: Equation: `Y[i]=(a**x)*(b**y)`. This are `a` and `b` for the equation, `x` and `y` are cell 'coordinates' in the matrix. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31295132/9413990

Comment: [-0.10133796  0.1456888  -0.01660059  0.54831516  0.45019822 -0.11496531]   powers : 

[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [2 0]
 [1 1]
 [0 2]]
prediction of [3,3] is

[8.23785927]    So, x=3 and y=3 in this case of prediction ?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the line

```
print(X_poly.powers_)
```

To

```
print(X_poly[0].powers_)
```

If the error disappears then loop through X_poly and print the value for each index of the array.

Comment: TypeError: 'PolynomialFeatures' object does not support indexin

Answer (score 0):

Split fitting into two lines, one for initializing other for fitting, also save the return value of the fit step so you can use it to train the LinearRegression model.

```
X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly_return = X_poly.fit_transform(X)
print(X_poly)
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)
model.fit(X_poly_return,y)
print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)
print(X_poly.powers_)
X_predict = np.array([[3,3]])
```

Comment: print ('prediction: \n')
print(model.predict(X_poly.transform(X_predict)))       i have to use this to display the predicted value ?

Comment: can you explain me this please powers : 

[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [2 0]
 [1 1]
 [0 2]]

Comment: Please check this link http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html

Comment: 1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2   is  [[0 0] [1 0] [0 1] [2 0] [1 1] [0 2]],  ? y=a*x*x+z*x ? any explanation please ?