# How to find regression curve equation for a fitted PolynomialFeatures model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

data=pd.DataFrame(
{"input": 
[0.001,0.015,0.066,0.151,0.266,0.402,0.45,0.499,0.598,0.646,0.738,0.782,0.86,0.894,0.924,0.95],
"output":[0.5263157894736842,0.5789473684210524,0.6315789473684206,0.6842105263157897, 
0.6315789473684206, 0.7894736842105263, 0.8421052631578945, 0.7894736842105263,  0.736842105263158,
0.6842105263157897,  0.736842105263158,  0.736842105263158,0.6842105263157897, 0.6842105263157897, 
0.6315789473684206,0.5789473684210524]})
```

I have the above data that includes input and output data and ı want to make a curve that properly fits this data. Firstly plotting of input and output values are here :
[image]

I have made this code:

```
X=data.iloc[:,0].to_numpy()
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
y=data.iloc[:,1].to_numpy()
y=y.reshape(-1,1)

poly=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly.fit(X,y)
X_poly=poly.transform(X)

reg=LinearRegression().fit(X_poly,y)
plt.scatter(X,y,color="blue")
plt.plot(X,reg.predict(X_poly),color="orange",label="Polynomial Linear Regression")
plt.xlabel("Temperature")
plt.ylabel("Pressure")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

plot is:

[image]

But ı don't find the above curve's equation (orange curve) how can ı find?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn: how to get coefficients of polynomial features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290976/sklearn-how-to-get-coefficients-of-polynomial-features)

Comment: Since you are using `PolynomialFeatures` from `sklearn` it will do all the work for you the equation will not be visible but you can think of it being a n-th degree Polynomial Equation which is best to fit for your data.

Comment: @JenilDave I am going to use this equation to get drag force by integrating, therefore have to determine. Maybe ı should use scipy regression?

Comment: @ashraful no ı can't find by this way

Comment: Please post the exact value of `degree` you have used for producing the plot (it does not correspond to `degree=2` which you show in your code, seems more like `degree=7`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plot actually corresponds to your code run with

```
poly=PolynomialFeatures(degree=7)
```

and not to `degree=2`. Indeed, running your code with the above change, we get:

[image]

Now, your polynomial features are:

```
poly.get_feature_names()
# ['1', 'x0', 'x0^2', 'x0^3', 'x0^4', 'x0^5', 'x0^6', 'x0^7']
```

and the respective coefficients of your linear regression are:

```
reg.coef_
# array([[   0.        ,    5.43894411,  -68.14277256,  364.28508827,
#         -941.70924401, 1254.89358662, -831.27091422,  216.43304954]])
```

plus the intercept:

```
reg.intercept_
# array([0.51228593])
```

Given the above, and setting

```
coef = reg.coef_[0]
```

since here we have a single feature in the initial data, your regression equation is:

```
y = reg.intercept_ + coef[0] + coef[1]*x + coef[2]*x**2 + coef[3]*x**3 + coef[4]*x**4 + coef[5]*x**5 + coef[6]*x**6 + coef[7]*x**7
```

For visual verification, we can plot the above function with some `x` data in `[0, 1]`

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 15)
```

Running the above expression for `y` and

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

gives:

[image]

Using some randomly generated data `x`, we can verify that the results of the equation `y_eq` are indeed equal to the results produced by the regression model `y_reg` within the limits of numerical precision:

```
x = np.random.rand(1,10)
y_eq = reg.intercept_ + coef[0] + coef[1]*x + coef[2]*x**2 + coef[3]*x**3 + coef[4]*x**4 + coef[5]*x**5 + coef[6]*x**6 + coef[7]*x**7
y_reg = np.concatenate(reg.predict(poly.transform(x.reshape(-1,1)))) 

y_eq
# array([[0.72452703, 0.64106819, 0.67394222, 0.71756648, 0.71102853,
#         0.63582055, 0.54243177, 0.71104983, 0.71287962, 0.6311952 ]])

y_reg
# array([0.72452703, 0.64106819, 0.67394222, 0.71756648, 0.71102853,
#        0.63582055, 0.54243177, 0.71104983, 0.71287962, 0.6311952 ])

np.allclose(y_reg, y_eq)
# True
```

---

Irrelevant to the question, I guess you already know that trying to fit such high order polynomials to so few data points is not a good idea, and you probably should remain to a low degree of 2 or 3...

Answer (score 1):

Note sure how you produced the plot shown in the question. When I ran your code I got the following (degree=2) polynomial fitted to the data as expected:

[image]

Now that you have fitted the data you can see the coefficients of the model thus:

```
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_)
# [[ 0.          0.85962436 -0.83796885]]
# [0.5523586]
```

Note that the data that was used to fit this model is equivalent to the following:

```
X_poly = np.concatenate([np.ones((16,1)), X, X**2], axis=1)
```

Therefore a single data point is a vector created as follows:

```
temp = 0.5
x = np.array([1, temp, temp**2]).reshape((1,3))
```

Your polynomial model is simply a linear model of the polynomial features:

y = A.x + B

or

```
y = reg.coef_.dot(x.T) + reg.intercept_
print(y) #  [[0.77267856]]
```

Verification:

```
print(reg.predict(x))  # array([[0.77267856]])
```